# Query which is not showing the desired result i.e order by date desc

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle query that is used to select data from the tables.But it is not showing date descending.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT cmoa.adate,
         subject,
         TYPE,
         to_char(cmoa.adate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') awarddate,
         (SELECT name
          FROM dopprod.cm_awards
          WHERE cm_awardsid = cmoa.awards) AS awardname
  FROM dopprod.cm_emp_master m
    INNER JOIN dopprod.cm_officer_awards cmoa ON m.cm_emp_masterid = cmoa.name
  WHERE m.cm_emp_masterid = '" + empcode + "'
)
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY awarddate) AS sno,
       subject,
       TYPE,
       awarddate,
       awardname
FROM dopprod.cte
ORDER BY sno
```

Comment: You haven't given the desc in the order by clause. Try something like order by cmoa.adate desc

Comment: Hi  Roshan  Thankyou but I have used  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY awarddate) do  ascending

Comment: did you got the desired result still looking ? As i see question is updated on order by with sno

Comment: `awarddate` isn't  a `date` but a `char`, so it is sorting it like a `char` - starting with all days 1, then all days 2 etc.

Comment: No Roshan still  figuring it  out.

Comment: Hie piet.t I have tried cmoa.adate  on the place  of  awarddate still same result.

Comment: And what would that result be....?

Comment: 02-01-2016 03-04-2017  23-12-2019 24-01-2016

Comment: thanks piet.t  I got  issue  sql is taking date in the form of character and sorting is happening that way

Answer (score 1):

Why would it show dates in descending order, if you didn't tell it so? Shouldn't it be

```
order by cmoa.adate DESC           --> your code is missing DESC
```

Comment: Thankyou so much   I have updated and used  order by with  AwardDate at last statement

Comment: You're welcome. If you thought that applying ASC (or DESC) within the ROW_NUMBER analytic function will affect the result - it will not. It will decide row numbers, yes - but not the way the final result is displayed on the screen. If possible, create a small test case so that we could work with your data and see what's going on and - finally - help you fix the problem.

Comment: As he is ordering by that rownumber the asc or desc of those should actually affect the result. I guess we have more of a datatype-problem here....

Comment: @piet.t, ORDER BY clause has been modified. Its original version was `ORDER BY cmoa.adate` (see edit history), and that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - you need to specify desc in order by

```
WITH cte
         AS (SELECT DISTINCT cmoa.adate,
                             subject,
                             TYPE,
                             TO_CHAR (cmoa.adate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AwardDate,
                             (SELECT Name
                                FROM dopprod.cm_awards
                               WHERE cm_awardsid = cmoa.awards)
                                AS awardname
               FROM dopprod.CM_EMP_MASTER m
                    INNER JOIN dopprod.cm_officer_awards cmoa
                       ON m.cm_emp_masterid = cmoa.name
              WHERE m.CM_EMP_MASTERID = 'someid')
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY cmoa.adate DESC) AS sno,
             subject,
             TYPE,
             AwardDate,
             awardname
        FROM dopprod.cte
    ORDER BY cmoa.adate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT rownum AS sno,
       subject, TYPE, awarddate, awardname
FROM dopprod.cte
ORDER BY adate DESC
```

If you want to sort by the *date* value, you need to include the *date* column, not the string column in the `order by`.

Comment: This query worked for me but sno is showing  1 5 2 3 4